# What does `if file` check for when uploading a file in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm following the [file uploads](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) example from the Flask docs.

There is an `if file` check before saving the file. When does this return false? It's already been checked that the file does exist and has a filename. It returns True when the file is empty.

If the file is None, the `file not in request.files` returns False, so the code never gets to the `if file` part. I just want to know why this check is done.

I have a feeling this question is probably silly and obvious, but I wasn't able to find anything on Google.

Snippet:

```
@app.route('/file/<string:filename>', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file(filename):
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return "No file part in request", 400
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return "No selected file", 400
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
        return "File uploaded successfully"
    else:
        return "Something went wrong but I don't know what", 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`request.files[]`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.files) returns a [`FileStorage`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) object, and from its source code, it's boolean value depends on the boolean value of its `filename`

```
def __nonzero__(self):
    return bool(self.filename)

__bool__ = __nonzero__
```

So the purpose of `if file` should be when the filename is not empty **but** falsy, I could though of `None` but I don't know how it could be this value, for me the filename could just be a string, empty of not, but that's how the tutorial suggest to do now.